# BillOutstandingAmount from ActiveMerchant response: Profile ID is missing from the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I have successfully created a profile id but when i try to use bill_outstanding_amount I get the following error : "Profile ID is missing from the request", even though I add the profile_id as parameter.

res = stargate.bill_outstanding_amount(profile_id,
                                    :amount => 888,
                                    :currency => "EUR"
                                    )

I am using this gem : https://github.com/rayvinly/active_merchant.git

And my xml looks like this :

```
  <BillOutstandingAmountReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
   <BillOutstandingAmountRequest xmlns:n2="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <n2:Version>62.0</n2:Version>
    <ProfileID>I-J58L6DFY53L1</ProfileID>
    <n2:Amount currencyID="EUR">8.88</n2:Amount>
   </BillOutstandingAmountRequest>
 </BillOutstandingAmountReq>
```

Need to mention that the profile_id is valid for a test account. If I use get_profile_details(profile_id) it returns a valid active user profile.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I have a feeling this might be a poor error message where the real problem is that there is no outstanding amount to bill. Unfortunately  I can't test that theory as I'm getting a 10001 "Internal Error" via the sandbox API now.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the namespace the tag..??  <n2:ProfileID>